# How can I pass parameters or references between consecutive tasks (JavaFX)?

Tags: java, spring-boot, javafx, task, java.util.concurrent

I have consecutive tasks triggered from the JavaFx main thread calling a service each one. The value I retrieve from one task should determine how the next task will behave. I've achieved it by methods (simplified example below) but it's a bit of spaghetti code.

```
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import java.util.concurrent.Executor;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class SomeControllerClass{

    private Executor exec;

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;
    @Autowired
    private SessionService sessionService;

    public void initialize() {
        exec = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(runnable -> {
            Thread t = new Thread(runnable);
            t.setDaemon(true);
            return t ;
            });
    }

    @FXML
    private void buttonAction(ActionEvent event){

        final String user = userTextField.getText().trim();
        final String pass = passTextField.getText().trim();

        Task<UserBean> task1 = new Task<UserBean>(){
            @Override
            protected UserBean call() throws Exception{
                return userService.getUserLogin(user, pass);
            }
        };
        task1.setOnSucceeded(e -> secondTask(task1.getValue()));
        task1.setOnFailed(e -> methodToNotifySomeException());
        exec.execute(task1);

    }

    private void secondTask(UserBean bean){

        //bean will be null only if the login failed
        if(bean==null) someLabel.setText("Wrong user or password");
        else{

            Task<Void> task2 = new Task<Void>(){
                @Override
                protected Void call() throws Exception{
                    sessionService.setActiveUser(bean);
                    return null;
                }
            };

            task2.setOnSucceeded(e -> methodToChangeScene());
            task2.setOnFailed(e -> manageSomeException());
            exec.execute(task2);
        }

    }

}
```

I also tried with [ExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) but it is roughly the same, I can't instantiate my consecutive task **and** find some way to the second one to retrieve a value from the first one without separating each task in a method.

Is there any Executor implementation I am missing that lets you pass parameters between tasks? Is there any "best practice" I'm totally unaware of that avoids all of these problems?

Comment: Have you explored the [Java Concurrency Utilities](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/concurrency/index.html) ? Do you know about [Phaser](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/util/concurrent/Phaser.html) or [Exchanger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Exchanger.html) ? Maybe one of them is what you are looking for?

Comment: I fail to spot any spaghetti. In fact there is just a single place where there are 2 possible execution branches.

Comment: If you are just trying to do a login, why even use a `Task`?  Maybe the `Task` for the userservice is good, but the second task is not. In the first `Task`, return a `Boolean` not `UserBean`.  Don't use a second `Task`. Just do the next action in the `onSucceeded` based on the returned `Boolean.